# Limit involving square root

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I'd like to know the value of the following limit
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow +\infty} \{ (t+1)^{\frac{1}{2}} - (t)^{\frac{1}{2}} \} = ?
$$

Comment: Multiplicate. $ $

Comment: Try multiplying by $\frac{\sqrt{t + 1} + \sqrt{t}}{\sqrt{t + 1} + \sqrt{t}}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, this is a typical home work question.

$$\lim_{t \to \infty}{\sqrt{t+1}-\sqrt{t}}=\lim_{t \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{t}(\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{t}}+1)}$$

Answer (score 2):

Problems of this type, can usually be handled by multiplying 
and dividing the given expression by the "conjugate of the square root part"
and using the formula $(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$:

$$\eqalign{
(t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} -t^{{1/2} }&=
\bigl((t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} -t^{{1/2}}\bigr)\cdot
\underbrace{{(t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} +t^{{1/2}}\over
(t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} +t^{{1/2}}}}_{=1}\cr
&=
{\bigl((t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} -t^{{1/2}}\bigr)
\bigl( (t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} +t^{{1/2}} \bigr)
\over(t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} +t^{{1/2}}}\cr
&={ (t+{1 })-t
\over(t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} +t^{{1/2}}}\cr
&={ 1
\over (t+{\textstyle{1 }})^{1/2} +t^{{1/2}}}.\cr
}
$$

You should be able to take the limit now...